# Append is working but remove is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, list, append

Code required to append list (anotherList) to item (id -= l1)  of second list (id= myList-toggle) but it should remove it after another click. But the remove is not working as expected. Some help in this regard expected.

```
 $('a#myList-toggle').click(function () {

                list.slice(0, counter()).slideToggle();

                 return false;

            });

            $('a#l1').click(function () {


                $('#l1').append($('#anotherList'));
               function () {
                   $('#al1').remove();
                };
                $('#anotherList').show();
                return false;

            });

        });



    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <div>
        <a href="#" id="myList-toggle">GO Now!!!!!!!</a></div>
    <ul id="myList" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
        <li><a href="#" id="l1">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="l4">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="l5">item3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="l6">item4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="A1">item5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="A2">item6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="A3">item7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="A4">item8</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="anotherList">
        <li class="al1">Item</li>
        <li class="al1">Item</li>
        <li class="al1">Item</li>
        <li class="al1">Item</li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>
```

Kindly tell if there is any other simple way to append and remove the list.

Comment: what is not expected? it doesn't remove? it removes the wrong thing? the code stops executing? if yes, where?

Comment: Thanks for reply Th0rndike!!!!! it doesn't do anything. It works fine but not do anything after clicking.

Comment: remove the function(){} wrapping $('#al1').remove()

Comment: Removed the function (){ wrapped around remove(). It append the list but not help to remove in another click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `$('#al1').remove();` to `$('.al1').remove();`

Also, whats with the `function() {` before remove?

I think its not necessary.

EDIT:

try this link: http://jsfiddle.net/9dVXg/

I think that's what you want to happen.

Comment: if functino (){ is removed it will not append the list to item l1 in the first list.

Comment: I'm talking about the `function() {` wrapping around `remove()`.  As other users has already pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for reply MegaNairda! Code want to remove the appended list in the second click. Tried with removing functin (){ wrapped around remove(). But second list will not appended to item in the first list. Clueless why this is happening. If you have another simple way to accopmlish this kindly explain.

Comment: Removed the function (){ wrapped around remove(). It append the list but not help to remove in another click.

Answer (score 3):

You have a function statement without name:

```
           function () {
               $('#al1').remove();
           };
```

This is not valid in Javascript, and your code likely throws an error, which stops your script execution.

You don't have an element with `id="al1"` in your HTML, thus `$('#al1')` selects nothing. Other answers have suggested that you need either `$('a#l1')` or `$('.al1')`, but it is not clear what exactly you want to remove.

It seems you're trying to toggle visibility of `#anotherList` when you click on `a#l1`. Probably a better approach would be to just render `#anotherList` as a child of the `a#l1` element from the beginning, and then in the `click` handler do `$('#anotherList').toggle()`. You might need to set the initial style of `#anotherList` to `display: none` if you want it to start in a hidden state.

Comment: Removed the function (){ wrapped around remove(). It append the list but not help to remove in another click.

Comment: Hi lanzz!!!!! My intention is to append the another list to the item of first list and remvoe the appended list in anothe click.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you typed the wrong thing?

```
$('a#l1').remove();
```

You typed `#al1` instead of `a#l1`

Or did you want to select the class?

```
$('.al1').remove()
```

The selector for **class** is `.` and for **id** is `#`

Comment: Thanks for reply! But code need to remove the appended list. $('a#l1').remove() will remove the original item in the first list to which the another list (id= anotherList) is appended.